# Is it possible to load an XML file using a variable name?

Tags: php

I know that to load a file we use

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("file.xml") or die("Error");
```

But i want something like

```
$target_dir = "directory/";
$target_file = $target_dir. basename ($_FILES["XMLfile"]["name"]);
$xml = simplexml_load_file($target_dir/$_FILES["XMLfile"]) or die("Error");
print_r($ xml);
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Why are there so many spaces in your code?

Comment: I corrected it @Phil

Comment: @nouvist I looked at the [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) but   I did not find what I was looking for

Comment: @nouvist i think that the problem is not in die function because once I run my code I get displayed this message `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types in C:\wamp64\www\plateformeWeb\gestionnaire.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\wamp64\www\plateformeWeb\gestionnaire.php on line 17`

Comment: A function never *sees* how it's parameters *come to be*. Meaning, in this context, if you can construct a valid file path, `simplexml_load_file` will work just the same. Which indicates that your file path or it's construction is wrong.

Comment: Is that supposed to be an arithmetic operation? `$target_dir/$_FILES["XMLfile"]`?

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: thanks to  @Yoshi and the others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it
it's

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file($target_dir.$_FILES["XMLfile"]["name"]) or die("Error");
```

not

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file($target_dir/$_FILES["XMLfile"]["name"]) or die("Error");
```

Comment: Are you sure you can omit slash between directory and file name?

Comment: I mean - shouldn't it be ```$target_dir.'/'.$_FILES["XMLfile"]["name"]``` ?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner i tried it but it doesn't work because the `/` is already in the variable `$target_dir`

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner but if we remove the `/` from the variable `$target_dir` your method must work

Comment: I suspected that :)